# Does a CSS3 animation run when parent element has visibility: hidden?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a CSS3 [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation) defined (and associated `@keyframes`):

```
animation: myAnimation 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.815, 0.735, 0.395) infinite;
```

Even though you can't see it, is this animation running (and consuming resource) if the parent element has `visibility: hidden`?

Comment: How would I do that? Try and look at CPU load? visibility: hidden = see nothing, visibility: visible = see animation.

Comment: Use a profiler, or generate 100 such animations and test w/ and w/o hidding visibility, see if there's a difference.

Comment: In any case, you might need to tag with a specific UA, because how much resources a certain operation requires is probably implementation dependent.

Comment: @Kong: Visibility setting doesn't stop the animations as far as I know. The animation keeps running even if the element has visibility as hidden because the element is still there, it is only hidden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the animations continue to run even if the parent container has `visibility:hidden` because the element is still there and it is only hidden. In the below snippet you can verify the contents of `.output` div to see that it keeps running and `marginLeft` keeps changing.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var animEl = document.querySelector('.animated');
  var outputEl = document.querySelector('.output');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    outputEl.textContent = 'Margin left when visibility becomes hidden: ' + window.getComputedStyle(animEl).marginLeft;
    document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      outputEl.textContent = 'Margin left when visibility becomes visible: ' + window.getComputedStyle(animEl).marginLeft;
      document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.wrapper{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.animated {
  animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  to {
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='animated'></div>
  <div class='sibling'></div>
</div>
<div class='output'></div>
```

---

As per [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/), only setting `display: none` terminates a running animation (and we can take that as won't start an animation also).

> Setting the display property to ‘none’ will terminate any running animation applied to the element and its descendants. If an element has a display of ‘none’, updating display to a value other than ‘none’ will start all animations applied to the element by the ‘animation-name’ property, as well as all animations applied to descendants with display other than ‘none’.

As you can see in the below snippet, the animation is terminated when `display` is set to `none` and **is restarted from first keyframe** when it is set back to `block`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var animEl = document.querySelector('.animated');
  var outputEl = document.querySelector('.output');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    outputEl.textContent = 'Margin left when display becomes none: ' + window.getComputedStyle(animEl).marginLeft;
    document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.display = 'none';
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      outputEl.textContent = 'Margin left when display becomes block: ' + window.getComputedStyle(animEl).marginLeft;
      document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.display = 'block';
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.animated {
  animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  to {
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='animated'></div>
  <div class='sibling'></div>
</div>
<div class='output'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on display: none.

Answer (score 2):

`visibility: hidden;` Does not stop animation. It will continue animation just doesn't display to you. But the space allocated to it will be there.

```css
p {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  margin-left:100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>The Caterpillar and Alice looked at each other for some time in silence:
at last the Caterpillar took the hookah out of its mouth, and addressed
her in a languid, sleepy voice.</p>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dhqmpkn/)**

You can check here scrollbar is keep moving even if `visibility:hidden`.